# Dropdown with autocomplete + static values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I want to create a dropdown when you click on an icon where you can search through data. I will clarify this with an image:

[image]

You can type your quiz name on the .... rule.
Then in the second part of the dropdwon you will see the quizzes from the database depending on the search terms.

In the third part of the dropdown I want to show the last 5 surveys (this has to be static, not chaning when the search terms change).

In the fourth part of the dropdown I also want to show static values.

Is this possible to do with [select2.js](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) ?
Or can someone help me start with this? I don't really have a clue on how to begin with this. I know how you can show data according to the search terms. But it's the third and fourth part of the dropdown that I don't really know how to show also under it ...

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: And could you give an example ? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use any dropdown api but if you want to autocomplete with static value you should use html5  form element  "`<datalist >`"

here is example

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```